# Angular Firebase auth signInWithRedirect in Ionic redirect issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have an Ionic app that requires a Google signin to login. The code is as follows;

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import AuthProvider = firebase.auth.AuthProvider;
constructor(
        private storage: Storage,
        private plt: Platform,
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
    ) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            this.user = user;
        });
        this.plt.ready().then(() => this.checkToken());
    }
private oauthSignIn(provider: AuthProvider) {
        if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
            return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(res => {
                this.storage
                    .set(TOKEN_KEY, res.user.refreshToken)
                    .then(result => {
                        this.authenticationState.next(true);
                    });
            });
        } else {
            return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() => {
                return this.afAuth.auth
                    .getRedirectResult()
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log(result);
                        const that = this;
                        this.storage
                            .set(TOKEN_KEY, result.user.refreshToken)
                            .then(res => {
                                that.authenticationState.next(true);
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        alert(error.message);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
```

Here, `signInWithPopup` works but not `signInWithRedirect`.

I checked this in browser and I am getting the user info and all.

But no information on the latter `else` functionality, which I separately checked.

But the real issue is, both the methods does not redirect to the app page once the permission is given.

The second one opens a browser in mobile once the login is clicked. But redirect backs to the browser rather than the app.

The same goes for the first if statement as well.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the app should watch the link redirected. Because the `signInWithRedirect` method redirect to link registered at the Firebase console.  So, you'll need a trick to watch the browser if the current URL is the redirect_uri registered.

The way to that is [explained here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova?hl=pt-br). Basically you should install the Universal Links and some other Cordova Plugins.

Comment: but its not the signinwithredirect only that has the issue, the same goes for the popup method as well.

Comment: can you please explain the plugins that are mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Basically i didn't get any answer mentioned in here working, and what @luis said may be correct it wasn't working for me.

So i decided to go with google plus plugin in ionic, that did the trick for me.
[google plus for ionic v4](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just redirect page after login, then you can use this...

```
this.fAuth.authState
        .subscribe(
          user => {
            if (user) {
              this.rootPage = HomePage;
            } else {
              this.rootPage = LoginPage;
            }
          },
          () => {
            this.rootPage = LoginPage;
          }
        );
```

put this code in app.component.ts file